# Why should I use Router on a Stick If already doing interVlan routing using L3 Switch in same netwrok?

Tags: routing, layer3

I have this network in which the top switch(one connected to router) is used for routing between all the vlans in the network.

[image]

I have defined `vlan interface` in this switch, but I haven't configured anything in a router on a stick.

My network below the router is working absolutely fine and I can ping every device from every other.

Now the scenario defined above is provided by my professor. Since everything is pinging properly , what am I supposed to configure in router on a stick ?

I know how to configure router on a stick using sub-interfaces and everything, but I am already using L3 Switching so why this router is even connected , and what am I supposed to configure in it ?

Comment: Are you supposed to configure both vlan routing on the multilayered switch and a router on a stick? It doesn't make sense to do both.

Comment: Unfortunately, homework questions are off-topic here.

Comment: The homework was to configure the entire network,.which i have already did. so I am not asking for help regarding the homework.

Comment: @Jimmy, I dont know, I had the network diagram given with the name if vlans which I supposed to create and a n Ip range to be used and also to use vlsm,.I have done everything, but what to do with the router ?

Comment: why not ask your professor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: if you **only** need to do inter-VLAN routing and you are already doing it with a L3 switch, then you don't **need** a router. Not to mention that switches are faster than routers at doing this because of ASIC.

Having said this, though, it makes sense to have a router in the picture because that's what you will find in the real world. You use routers to connect remote LANs via WAN links, you use them for QoS, ACLs etc. You need to be able to configure routers even when they are connected to L3 switches which do some of the routing.

Then again, if you just need to configure inter-VLAN routing, you are good to go, no need to configure it on the router as well because the switch is already taking care of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any explicit instructions to configure vlan routing on the multilayered switch or to use a Router-on-a-stick, you can choose the method you prefer.

But since the diagram doesn't show that Router 0 is supposed to connect the switches to other networks, I think it's meant to be used as a router-on-a-stick. Hence you should not use the multilayered switch to route the vlans but instead trunk them to the router.

Answer (score 0):

Your internal LAN will work fine with the multi-layer switch as your trunk. But what is the point if you can't get your devices on the internet to do work? The router is the device that will strip the LAN/VLAN headers and find destinations outside of your LAN. Otherwise you've just created an internal network that is solely used to connect devices to each other. Not very practical in an enterprise or even home environment.